# Can I pass an async function as a callback to an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere...

I'm trying to use setState to update the state of my app but, I need to call an `async` function after `setState` is finished.
Can I `await` an `async` function inside the callback for `setState`?

```
 setState({foo: bar}, async () => {await doStuff()});
```

Also assuming that this works, can I rely on `setState` finishing before `doStuff` is called, and can I rely on `doStuff` being `await`ed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, indeed you can. The special thing about async functions is that they always return Promises, so especially for functions whose return value is not important (callbacks, for example), you can safely put in an async function, and it would work as expected.

Taking this one step further, you can even have an async function as your `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` for example (but still not `render`, which expects a JSX element to be returned, not a Promise).

Comment: The point about the return value not being important is the key thing here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The callback of the setState only fires when the state is updated so doStaff will not execute until state is updated.
You can define the callback as async function and await inside it as any other function.

```
const setStateAsync = (newState) => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
       setState(newState, resolve);
   });
```

you can use it like this Ex:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    await setStateAsync(newState);
    await doStuff()
 }
```

Comment: I didn't want to change the function I'm in to async, but it's definitely an option as well.

Comment: Both will work. I wanted to share with another way, i am a fan of async/await :)